# Conditional type

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If  each  stripe  melted in  about  an  hour,  about  three  hours  would  have passed when three stripes melt.

What type of conditional is it? I did not find the type of "If past tense, would have perfect".

Comment: The sentence doesn't look correct to me.  I would never say "when three stripes melt", I would say "when three stripes *had melted*."

Comment: @stangdon's right. And you won't find this in the "first, second, third conditionals", which are just teaching devices and don't come close to representing the many possible combinations of verbforms and verb constructions which are used in English conditionals. You understand how conditionals work, so throw away the baby rules.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the "non-conditional" form of what you're saying, as well as a word you really need for it to be clear.

> Each stripe melts in about an hour, [therefore] about three hours pass when three stripes melt.

Did three actual stripes melt?  Then you say this:

> If each stripe melts in about an hour, then about three hours *have passed* for those melted stripes.

Are we talking about a possibility of stripes melting?  Then you say this:

> If each stripe melts in about an hour, then about three hours would have passed for those melted stripes.

If you really want to use the *when* phrase, you should say *when all three have melted* or *when all three would have melted.*

Comment: I know it emphasizes only "would have perfect" not "conditional if".

Answer (score 0):

I would say a **Conditional type 2**, with corrections to keep it "grammatically neat".

As a Conditional type 1 we would say: If one stripe **melts** in an hour, then about three hours **will have passed**, when three strips **have melted**.

So, to make the above a Conditional type 2: If one stripe **melted** in an hour, then about three hours **would have passed**, when three stripes **melted**.

(Here we must use **would have** to signify one action completed before the other: If I **had** enough materials, I **would have finished** before 3 pm today. We try to **look back from the future 3pm**, and **pretend** we describe the past).

And Type 3: If one stripe **had melted** in an hour, then about three hours **would have passed**, when three stripes **had melted**.